# Url works fine on browser but returns null on Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

When I test my URL on a browser, it returns JSON data from the server. But it returns null on Android when I call it from AsyncTask. I looked for an answer on Google but I didn't find anything. Can anyone help me, please?

```
 public List<User> getUsers() {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        final String OUTPUT = "Output";
        URL url = new URL("MyUrl");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(br.readLine());
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //users = mapper.readValue(output, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, User.class));
        conn.disconnect();
        Log.d(OUTPUT,output);//I get null here
        return users;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}
```

This is my AsyncTask:

```
public class GetUsersTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,List> {
    @Override
    protected List doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        UserClient client = new UserClient();
        List users = client.getUsers();
        return users;
    }
}
```

And this is how i call it:

```
usersTask = new GetUsersTask();
usersTask.execute();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Thanks in advance`. Bad habit. Why are you chasing people away?

Comment: `Log.d(OUTPUT,output);//I get null here`. That is impossible as sb.toString() will return "" when empty.

Comment: 02-09 00:00:05.061 19197-20157/myapp.com.mynewapp I/System.out: Output from Server .... 
02-09 00:00:05.061 19197-20157/myapp.com.mynewapp D/Output:: null

Comment: This is from logcat

Comment: `while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(br.readLine());`. You only add every second line. The one in the while() you throw away.

Comment: Please, add a right variant.How must i do it?

Comment: String line; while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {sb.append(line+"\n");}

Comment: Great !! It worked.Thank you very much!!